# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject, do I need set @result?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hi I'm building a preference center and I can update fields in Salesforce two ways. The documentation shows to use SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject but I was able to update a field without using SET @result. Do I need SET @result?

This is what I have and both ways work

```
  set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',@CaseSafeID,'MobilePhone',@MobilePhone)
  set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',@CaseSafeID,'Subscribe_to_SMS_Messages__c',@SMSOptIn)

  UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',@CaseSafeID,'FirstName',@FirstName)
```

Comment: Do you care if the update was successful?

Comment: Yes I was planning to add those checks at some point

Comment: It returns 1 for success or 0 for failure.

Comment: So I need to use that if I want to see if the update was successful?

Comment: You would likely use that to control user feedback if the operation was successful. People like to know if their desired action was successful (or not).

Comment: You don't need to do all those updates separately. You can just add them as a list of name/values. ------ex.------   SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',@CaseSafeID,'MobilePhone',@MobilePhone,'Subscribe_to_SMS_Messages__c',@SMSOptIn,'FirstName',@FirstName)

Comment: hey @victorcorey thanks for the tip, I will give that a try!

Comment: If someone wants some cred, post the right answer so I can mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UpdateSingleSalesforceObject() returns 1 for success or 0 for failure. So if you want to validate if the update was successful you should store the return value in a variable (ex. @result).

In addition you can update multiple fields at once by passing in a series of name/value pairs.

```
SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead',@CaseSafeID,'MobilePhone‌​',@MobilePhone,'Subs‌​cribe_to_SMS_Message‌​s__c',@SMSOptIn,'Fir‌​stName',@FirstName)
```